# Full screen for selenium. What to do?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to perform a keyboard key function on selenium using pycharm to write script. I want to perform the F11 key i.e: go full screen and back to normal window using selenium, but the script i am using does not perform any function and the driver quits after the give time delay. I am using the chrome driver for my script. Please help.

I am using it on windows 8.1 
with pycham education version 
python 3.7
selenium for python 3.14

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"A:\full screen\browser\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(2)
print("google")
act = ActionChains(driver)
act.send_keys(Keys.F11).perform()
print("fullscreen")
time.sleep(2)
act.send_keys(Keys.F11).perform()
print("fullscreen exit")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

my expected result is to go full screen and back to normal window and then exit the chrome driver.

Comment: try : `driver.fullscreen_window()` if you are just trying to toggle to full screen on.

Comment: and how do i exit from that but not quit the driver.

Comment: driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

Comment: i tried driver.maximize_window() and it worked. but ruins the further process by saying an error as
failed to change window state to normal, current state is maximized

Comment: driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='75 %'")

also this command is not working for me in chrome driver